# count() and concordance() give different counts

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying python nltk.

While

```
>>> from nltk.book import *
>>> text1.concordance("monstrous")
Displaying 11 of 11 matches:
...
```

gives 11 matches and shows all of them,

```
>>> text1.count("monstrous")
10
```

gives only 10. Why is there a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text1.concordance()` is  **not** case sensitive but `text1.count()` **is** case sensitive.

So if you look at the output there is  a `"Monstrous"` capital `"M"` in the text so that is the difference in the totals

If you `print text1.count("Monstrous")` it will return `1`.